# Inaccurate voltage reading from MCP6234 op-amp buffer circuit with Seeed XIAO nRF52840

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, analog, current-transformer

I'm facing an issue when trying to read the voltage output from an analog sensor (current transformer) that has a DC voltage output of 0-5 V, using a Seeed XIAO nRF52840 to read the output using its ADC. The nRF52840 has 3.3 V logic, so I can't connect the sensor directly to the ADC.

Initially, I tried using a voltage divider to cut the voltage in half, but the CT sensor requires 1 MΩ of impedance to operate properly, and it doesn't output much current. This resulted in inaccurate ADC readings. To overcome this, I switched to using an op-amp buffer circuit with an MCP6234 op-amp. I've connected it as shown in the diagram below:

[image: op-amp-circuit]

The issue I'm experiencing now is that the voltage output is off by roughly +0.03 V. Here are some things I've tried so far:

Connecting the circuit directly to the ADC with a lower-than-3.3V voltage output: This resulted in a very accurate reading with an error of approximately +0.001 V.
Removing the capacitor and the 10 kΩ resistor from the circuit didn't result in any noticeable change in the output.

I'm not sure what else I might be missing or what could be causing this inaccuracy. Any suggestions or insights on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the contributors to your error budget.  I left in the negligible contributions to help you in choosing components.

Resistor tolerance:  Standard resistors have a tolerance of 1 % which would lead to an error of up to .033 volts with a 3.3-volt range.

Op amp input offset voltage is 5 mv, so up top .005 volts of error is introduced here.

Op amp input offset current is 1 picoamp, which can cause a 0.24 uV error.

Op amp input bias current is 1 picoamp, which can cause a 0.24 uV error.  This can be correct with a feedback resistor near 235K instead of 10K.

Since you are getting adequate accuracy when applying a known voltage, your problem does not seem to be in the processor.  However:

nRF52840 processor claims effective 9-bit accuracy, adding a potential .006 volts.  You are already doing better than this.

nRF52840: watch your acquisition times.

nRF52840 processor has an internal offset calibration step that should be initiated.

I think to achieve the accuracy you want you will need precision resistors or a potentiometer to trim the resistor divider.  You might also need to trim the offset or choose an Op Amp with a lower input offset voltage.